# I need some clues using chart

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, charts

I'm n00bie. so sorry if it would be not an appropriate question for some of you. Maybe someone would help me tho. I wanna develop an easy tool with some controls and ajax-updatable chart(based on MVC) in C#/.net. I have found a simple  and clean tutorial.But it was wirtitten  in 2010. I'm wondering if it is kinda modern? Or has changed anything and this style is already old? I'm  especially interested if it is a good idea to use jquery to perform an update on a chart after some buttons were pressed?

I'm also including a snippet from this tutorial, so maybe you get me better:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Annual Sales Data (With Fancy JavaScript!)
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Populate the Categories and Years DDLs with the values from the server
        $.getJSON('/Api/Years',        // URL that returns data of interest
                  function (result) {       // The function that executes once the data has been returned
                      var years = $("#years");
                      $.each(result, function (index, year) {
                          years.append($("<option />").val(year).text(year));
                      });

                      $.getJSON('<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Api/Categories")%>',        // URL that returns data of interest
                          function (result) {       // The function that executes once the data has been returned
                              var categories = $("#categories");
                              $.each(result, function (index, categoryName) {
                                  categories.append($("<option />").val(categoryName).text(categoryName));
                              });

                              // Load the image
                              UpdateImage();
                           });
                  });

            // Add client-side event handlers to these DDLs
            $("#years").change(UpdateImage);
            $("#categories").change(UpdateImage);
        });

        function UpdateImage() {
            var selectedYear = $("#years").val();
            var selectedCategory = $("#categories").val();

            $("#chart").fadeOut(function () {
                $(this).attr('src', '/Charts/SalesByYear?CategoryName=' + escape(selectedCategory) + '&OrderYear=' + escape(selectedYear) + '&showTitle=false')
                       .attr('alt', 'Sales for ' + selectedCategory + ' in ' + selectedYear)
                       .attr('title', 'Sales for ' + selectedCategory + ' in ' + selectedYear);

                $(this).fadeIn();
            });
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Annaul Sales Data (With Fancy JavaScript)</h2>
    <p>
        This demo shows how to gussy up the sales data charting example using a tad of JavaScript and jQuery.
    </p>
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <h2 style="text-align: center">Sales For <select id="categories"></select> In <select id="years"></select></h2>
        <img id="chart" style="display:none" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Could anyone recommend me any tutorial in which I'd be able to ee how can I implement a mvc-based web app with using flotcharts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would look at something like flot http://www.flotcharts.org/
Rather than generate an image on the server side.

Comment: Thank you for response. What disadvantage do I have when I would generate image on server? But you'd do the controllers in c#, don't you?

Comment: Could anyone recommend me any tutorial in which I'd be able to see how can I implement a mvc-based web app with using flotcharts?

Answer (score -1):

You might want to check [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/). Its a very good graph plugin using jQuery.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer. Could you recommend me any tutorial, in which I would be able to see how can I use it with mvc/c#?

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't specific enough. I'm looking for a good tutorial for a mvc 4 based solution, which also uses jqplot. And I would love to be able to  download the whole solution.